# I am getting an error while connecting jdbc with mysql server inside a servlet project file

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

Using eclipse i was trying to connect with mysql inside a servlet program but i am getting same error again and again even though i have set the classpath for mysql connector

`this is the error i am getting`

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javasql
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at in.ineuron.controller.Connect.init(Connect.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1063)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
null
```

And this is my code which i am trying to run in eclipse

```
package in.ineuron.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Connect
 */
@WebServlet(
        urlPatterns = { "/reg" }, 
        initParams = { 
                @WebInitParam(name = "url", value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javasql"), 
                @WebInitParam(name = "user", value = "root"), 
                @WebInitParam(name = "password", value = "password")
        })
public class Connect extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
        String url = config.getInitParameter("url");
        String user = config.getInitParameter("user");
        String password = config.getInitParameter("password");
        
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(connection);
        
    }
```

}

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH7xR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHDGA.png)
Here i have set the jar file in the classpath of eclipse

Comment: Set the classpath how?

Comment: It has been a while since I had to do this, but I remember randomly having to do something like this: `Class.forName("com.example.jdbc.Driver");` in order to load the driver into the program. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Connection variable!   Only a global variable can be declared null !   Variables inside methods e.g. init must be assigned at the moment they are declared, they are not allowed to be null!

Comment: @SamuelMarchant That's not true. Anything that's not a primitive can be null--in fact the default value for objects when there's no assignment statement.

Comment: No doubt anything can be assigned null but to remove null after assignment of null is only allowed on global  variables. Also, only complex types use null. Connection variable must be global if it is first null.  Oddly, the point of init() generally is to instantiate the global's in the class.